# Worksheet_SelectionChange not performing desired task

Tags: vba, excel

**Background:**

I don't appear to know what I'm doing with SelectionChange and would like some help to ensure I'm using it correctly.

I have right-clicked *This Workbook*, in the VBA window, and selected *View Code*.  I have my code in that field.  In the immediate window (ctrl+g), I have input:

```
Application.EnableEvents=True
```

---

**Code:**

The code I'm using to test is supposed to display the target row/column in a cells(1,1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r, c As Integer
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        c = Target.Column
        r = Target.Row
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Cells(" & r & ", " & c & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Question:**

Am I missing something to enable the selection change event?

Comment: In ThisWorkbook, the correct name is `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`. You can find all the names from the dropdowns at the top of the VBE. Add to the sheet module if you want it to apply to a single sheet only.

Comment: @SJR After correcting the name and some playing around, this seems to be acting similar to a regualar change event, where the change of activecell (selection) isn't the trigger, but entering the cell to edit the string is the trigger.  You answered my posted question with the correct name.  Will look to post my other question about the functionality separately.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be triggered by the cell being selected rather than having to edit it. It should be no different to the normal sheet-level selection change event, the only difference being that you can specify a worksheet(s) to which it applies.

Comment: @SJR Hm... in trying to test some more, only after exiting a cell which I was just edited text does the Cells(1,1).Value update to display Cells(activecell.row, activecell.column).

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have any other event code which may override (I'm not sure which takes precedence)?

Comment: @SJR I opened a new, blank workbook which only has this code inside.  There shouldn't be anything else over-riding.

Comment: @SJR making it a Sheet specific event fixed that issue; it wasn't working in the Workbook specific event.  Definitely worth noting for the future that I will need to put the change event into each Sheets code.  Thank you for the help!  CLR's answer got me all dots connected, as it explained what was supposed to happen with each level (ThisWorkbook or Sheet).

Comment: Odd. You're definitely using `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`? When I first posted I put the wrong one down, not sure if you saw that.

Comment: Yes but the advantage of the workbook level is that you don't have to specify it for each sheet, and it should work. I have no idea why it isn't for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on **ThisWorkbook** and select *View Code* you will see two dropdowns above the code window. The leftmost allows you to select (General) or **Workbook**. If you select Workbook, the rightmost dropdown will provide all the events you can utilise at the Workbook level. Worksheet_SelectionChange is not there as it's not a Workbook level event.

Workbook level events include events like **Open**, **Close** and **SheetChange**. Note: **SheetChange** fires when the user changes the sheet selected, not makes a change to a given sheet.

If you do the same but with the **Sheet1 (Sheet1)** object, the leftmost dropdown will show (General) and **Worksheet**. Selecting this will provide the events available at the Worksheet level. Pick **SelectionChange** and the VBE will automatically create the shell of the event ready for you to populate with your code.

Note, this event will only fire if a cell is changed on the sheet you've added the code to so keep this in mind when creating your event(s).

Comment: This. **NEVER** type up event handler signatures by hand, or paste them in. Unless you know **exactly** what you're doing and that you know and remember the exact name of the event and the event provider interface, as well as the number, type, and ordering of every single parameter in the signature (note, names don't matter). Handlers are always named `Interface_EventName`, as are interface implementations - `Interface_MemberName`. And BTW that's why you should never have underscores in your method names.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about what each level Event included.  That's what clicked with me and fixed all the issues I was having.  @SJR got me on the right track to start, though you provided more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't right click on `ThisWorkbook`, instead, right click on the `Sheet1`.